# Does "quite sorry" sound common to you?

Tags: meaning

Phrases like "*so sorry*", "*very sorry*" are commonly seen, but "*quite sorry*" sounds odd to me. At first I thought it might be because "*quite*" doesn't usually go with words representing negative meanings. for example, "*quite good*" sounds common to me, yet "*quite bad*" somehow sounds off (maybe I would say "*not quite good*" instead). I know there's nothing grammatically wrong with "*quite sorry*", so I'ld like to know how others feel about the word "***quite***" going with words representing negative meanings. Thank you!

Comment: *Quite bad* sounds fine to me.  Although I've never heard *quite sorry*, I have heard *I'm quite sorry*.

Comment: I might say *quite sorry* if I was talking about someone for whom it had not occurred to anyone to feel sorry for; and where the degree of feeling sorry is not overwhelming. Currently I feel 'quite sorry' for Steve Gerrard, who has just ended his career as the England football captain, since it has come at a low point in the team's fortunes. So he is going out on a low.

Answer (score 2):

When you apologise to someone, you want it to be as sincere as possible.

*"Very"* and *"so"* are both words that make something more - *"so cool"*, *"very cool"*.

*"quite"* however, is a limiter. Compare *"quite cool"* to *"cool"*, the object that is just "*cool"* is better than the object that is *"quite cool"*.

In the same way, being *"quite sorry"* suggests you don't care much about the person you are apologising to.

Comment: ... Which makes it sound like you're an a-hole. That's why people don't use it; you usually don't say sorry just to sound like you don't care.